# Copying files with wildcard (*) to a folder in a bash script - why isn't it working?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I am writing a bash script that creates a folder, and copies files to that folder. It works from the command line, but not from my script. What is wrong here?

```
#! /bin/sh
DIR_NAME=files

ROOT=..
FOOD_DIR=food
FRUITS_DIR=fruits

rm -rf $DIR_NAME
mkdir $DIR_NAME
chmod 755 $DIR_NAME

cp $ROOT/$FOOD_DIR/"*" $DIR_NAME/
```

I get:

```
cp: cannot stat `../food/fruits/*': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Putting the wildcard in quotes means you're looking for a file with the name `*`, not expanding it to a list of files.

Comment: OMG... I didn't have it in quotes before but it wasn't working, but for a different reason. Never thought to change it back. *pacepalm*. Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You got that exactly backwards -- everything **except** the `*` character should be double-quoted:

```
#!/bin/sh
dir_name=files

root=..
food_dir=food
fruits_dir=fruits

rm -rf "$dir_name"
mkdir "$dir_name"
chmod 755 "$dir_name"

cp "$root/$food_dir/"* "$dir_name/"
```

Also, as a matter of best-practice / convention, non-environment variable names should be lower case to avoid name conflicts with environment variables and builtins.

Comment: can you elaborate on what 'environment variable' names are?

Comment: @myol, an environment variable is a variable stored in process space where any child processes can read it; the POSIX guidelines for their naming are given in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, advising that variables used or set by operating system components have all-uppercase names, and specifying that names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for application use; thus, sticking to names with at least one lower-case character don't risk conflicting with variable names that modify OS component behavior.

Comment: ...this is relevant even for non-exported shell variables, because if you assign a shell variable with a name that's also present in the environment, then the environment variable with that name will be updated as well, making it possible to overwrite environment variables by mistake. (As an effect of this, it's actually unnecessary to use `export` when updating `PATH`; it'll pick up updates as long as it's already in the environment).

Comment: Thank you I did not know about this convention. I shall update my scripts now

Comment: For `cp "/usr/local/lib/libboost"* "./"` I get
`cp: cannot stat ‘/usr/local/lib/libboost*’: No such file or directory`. So this is incorrect or there's a catch.

Comment: @TomášZato, you'll need to prove to me that there really *is* a match before that error message is indicative of something being wrong. Does `ls -l /usr/local/lib/libboost*` show matches? A log showing your script run with `set -x` (aka `bash -x yourscript`) would also be helpful, though it's liable to be getting out-of-scope from a comment-thread discussion.

Comment: @TomášZato, ...to be clear, leaving the `*` unexpanded even when unquoted is default behavior for the shell when no matches are found. (On bash, that default can be changed by enabling the `failglob` or `nullglob` options, triggering a failure or expanding to a zero-length result list respectively).