# Shell Script: Copying files with wildcard (*) to from one folder to another folder

Tags: shell, zsh

A very simple question but bothers me. I want to copy all files in one folder to another folder in a shell script. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp data/* /tmp/data
```

But got `error: zsh:1: no matches found: data/*`

Reading various posts on stackoverflow, like here: [Copying files with wildcard (*) to a folder in a bash script - why isn't it working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21924351/copying-files-with-wildcard-to-a-folder-in-a-bash-script-why-isnt-it-work)
I have tried:

```
cp "data"/* /tmp/data
Error: zsh:1: no matches found: data/*
cp -r data /tmp/data
Error cp: cannot stat `data': No such file or directory
```

I could verify data folder contains files, and I'm in the parent directory data folder. If I do `ls data` in the script, the contents of it are correctly printed.

Could anyone help? I'm using zsh.

Comment: What is the current working directory when you run the script? (That is, what is the output if you call `pwd` just before you call `cp`?

Comment: How are you running the script? I'm surprised you're getting a zsh error about `data/*` on line 1 when this is a `sh` script where line 1 is a comment.

Comment: @chepner Current directory is the parent directory of data. Like I said if I added `ls data` after the cp command in the script, it would print the folder contents correctly.

Comment: @thatotherguy There is actually a wrapper shell scrip to run multiple commands in the sub script, which runs each command separately. The whole set has been working fine, but recently the `cp` got broken after migrated to a new machine. I could do `ls` on data folder, but the `cp` doesn't work.

Comment: How did the data folder get created? I'm picturing a scenario like this: you had a script with DOS line endings that executed a command like `mkdir data`, which resulted in a directory named `data\r` (with the `\r` representing a carriage return) being created. Your `cp` command fails because the directory name is `data\r`, not `data`, but `ls data` succeeds for the same reason `mkdir data` created the faulty directory name: `data` was the last argument on the line.

Answer (score 1):

I think the command you are looking for might be `cp -r data /tmp/`. It will create the `data` directory in `/tmp/`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with the destination fix. But the problem here is that the command cannot recognize the 'data' folder at all.

Comment: Historic versions of the `cp` utility had a `-r` option.  This implementation supports that option; however, its use is strongly discouraged, as it does not correctly copy special files, symbolic links, or fifo's.

Comment: @ruyuan That could be because the "data" directory that the shell is complaining about is the /tmp/data directory, since it doesn't exist yet, or the working directory that you are running the command from is not in the same directory as "data", where you will have to either provide the full path, or change to the directory first before copying.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cp "data/*" /tmp/data
```

It works for me.